# Convert array of integer to an integer in php

Tags: php

I'm using this code, to convert an array of ints to an int

```
return intval(implode("",$result));
```

then from

```
[5,6,7]
```

I get

```
567
```

There is a more direct way to make this conversion?

Comment: What is the problem with your current method?

Comment: How much more direct can you get?

Comment: You could use `foreach` loop or `array_reduce()` to calculate the result, but it won't be clearer.

Comment: `return (int)implode($result);` shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intval` or `cast`, but you can convert without use any string.

```php
<?php
$result = [5,6,7];
//string using intval

$integer1 = intval(implode("",$result)); 
var_dump($integer1);
//567

//string using cast
$integer2 = (int) implode("",$result); 
var_dump($integer2);
//567

//if you don't like strings
$integer3 = array_of_int_to_int($result);
var_dump($integer3);
//567

//using pow of 10 for convert to integer
function array_of_int_to_int($array){
  $integer = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    $integer += ($array[$i] * pow(10, count($array) - ($i + 1)));
  }
  return $integer;
}
//integer = 500 + 60 + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_reduce` with two different methods **String Concatenation** or **Math Logic**:

##### String Concatination

```php
$nums = [5,6,7];
$result = (int)array_reduce($nums, function ($acc, $el) {
    $acc .= $el;
    return $acc;
},'');
echo $result; //567
/*
=> ''
 ''.5 => '5'
 '5'.6 => '56'
 '56'.7 => '567'
*/
```

##### Math Logic

```php
$exponent = count($nums)-1; //2
$result = array_reduce($nums, function ($acc, $el) use (&$exponent) {
    $acc += $el * 10**$exponent;
    $exponent--;
    return $acc;
}, 0);
echo $result; //567
/*
=> 0
 5 * 10**2  =>  500
 6 * 10**1  =>  560
 7 * 10**0  =>  567
*/
```